# For the parabola $(y-3)^2 = 6(x+2)$, what are the vertex-to-focus, vertex-to-directrix, and focus-to-directrix distances?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

I am trying to get ahead in a class and I don't know how to answer the following questions:

> What is the distance from the vertex to the focus for the parabola
> $$(y-3)^2 = 6(x+2)$$
> What is the shortest distance from the vertex to the directrix for this parabola?
>
> What is the shortest distance from the focus to the directrix for this parabola?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting anyone's time explaining what you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. Isolated problem statements tend to give the wrong impression.) In this case ... If you knew the answer to your first question (or any of them), could you answer the other two?

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm trying to receive help and I don't know where to begin since the course provides very minimal instruction in conics. I calculated the vertices, but moving beyond that point is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex lies at the point $$(-2,3)$$ and focus lies at the point $(-\dfrac{1}{2}, 3)$ and equation of directrix is, $x=-7/2$

Now the distance between vertex and focus will be equal to $$-\dfrac12-(-2)=\dfrac32$$

The distance between vertex and directrix will be equal to $$-2-(-7/2)=3/2$$

The distance between focus and directrix will be equal to $$3/2+3/2=3$$

Comment: The directrix is vertical in this case, not horizontal as you have it.

Comment: Yes, vertical directrix has equation $x=-7/2$ so what is wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it - my brain is another matter though :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at a more general case first.

The distance from the focus to each point on the parabola equals the distance from that point to the directrix.  And this distance is minimized at the vertex.

Let's start with a parabola with focus $(p,0)$ and directrix $y = -p$

$p$ is the distance from focus to vertex, and from vertex to directrix.

The points on the parabola are the $(x,y)$ pairs such that:

$\sqrt {(x-p)^2 + y^2} = x+p$

Squaring both sides and expanding the binomials

$x^2 -2px + p^2 + y^2 = x^2 + 2px + p^2\\
y^2 = 4px$

That last line is the key to this whole problem.

Tranlating the parabola $(y-3)^2 = 4p(x+2)$ does nothing to change $p$

Now, it is quite likely that you have already derived all of this already. And, it would be fine to start here:

$4p = 6\\
p = \frac 32$

Comment: My comment on @TShiong's answer should have been a comment on this answer: the directrix is parallel to the y-axis in this case, so its equation is $x = -p$.